# Jquery cycle plugin - Multiple divs with cycle plugin from one script?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-cycle

Im new to jquery/javascript and need help!

I want to use the cycle plugin in multiple divs with different images in each div. Each div is the same size and each image is the same size.

The code I have used so far shows all images in the first div but when I click on my logo (which is linked to index.html) all the images suddenly appear in place and working with the cycle plugin.

This is what I have in the head

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#box1').cycle({ 
                        fx:     'fade', 
                       speed:   300, 
                       timeout: 0, 
                       next:   '#box1', 
                       pause:   1  
                });
            });

            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#box2').cycle({ 
                        fx:     'fade', 
                       speed:   300, 
                       timeout: 0, 
                       next:   '#box2', 
                       pause:   1  
                });
            });

            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#box3').cycle({ 
                        fx:     'fade', 
                       speed:   300, 
                       timeout: 0, 
                       next:   '#box3', 
                       pause:   1  
                });
            });
        </script>
```

body...

```
<div id="container">


            <div id="box1" class="box">
            <img src="images/car.jpg" alt="images/car.jpg"/>
            <img src="images/van.jpg" alt="images/van.jpg"/>
            </div>


            <div id="box2" class="box">
            <img src="images/bottle.jpg" alt="images/bottle.jpg"/>
            <img src="images/pattern.jpg" alt="images/pattern.jpg"/>
            </div>

            <div id="box3" class="box">
            <img src="images/car.jpg" alt="images/car.jpg"/>
            <img src="images/van.jpg" alt="images/van.jpg"/>
            </div>
    </div>
```

In the css the container is position: absolute;

I'm sure there is a simple solution but I have searched stackoverflow and other sites to no avail. Any help is greatly appreciated!!!!

Comment: One comment: You should include all your `$('#box').cycle()` within *one* `$(document).ready()`.
What is the expected behaviour?

Comment: Hi Luiggi. The expected behaviour is that each individual div will have it's own individual cycle of images. As it currently stands all of my images appear in the first div until I click on my logo, which is linked to index.html, in which case all of the images appear in their correct divs and run the cycle plugin fine. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Also I have done what you said in the above comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/YHLz2/11/

```
$(function() {
    $('.box').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.cycle({
            fx: 'fade',
            speed: 300,
            timeout: 0,
            next: $this,
            pause: 1
        });
    });
});​
```

it works as expected, yours too.  May be you use too old jquery ?  (current is 1.8)

if answer not fit your problem, can you please edit jsfiddle to show where the problem ?

---

- **when I load the page**
- **when I click on my logo**, linked to index.html

I think **when you load the page** you load not index.html, but index.htm, or index.php or something else, check your site directory

*The jsfiddle should repeat your problem, not just show your structure*

*if your site on the internet - give me link and i will check*

---

Try to change your code to the following:

```
   $(document).load(function() {
    $('.box').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.cycle({
            fx: 'fade',
            speed: 300,
            timeout: 0,
            next: $this,
            pause: 1
        });
    });
});​
```

Comment: Hi eicto. The jquery I was using was old so I've updated that to current version but the same results as before. I've added some css to the jsfiddle and placed the images in similar fashion to my site. Maybe that will help?..I forgot to mention above that this is a horizontal website. Also it works perfect every time in firefox but not in chrome or safari.

Comment: As is the jqeury seems to be working fine but when I open the page all of the images, regardless of what div they are placed in, appear on top of each other in the first div. Maybe this is a problem with my css?

Comment: Unfortunately no...As it currently stands all of my images appear in the first div until I click on my logo, which is linked to index.html, in which case all of the images appear in their correct divs and run the cycle plugin fine. I'm baffled by this.

Comment: can you repeat the problem ? i see no logo in fiddle

Comment: I tried the new reduced code. It didnt even partially run the plugin which is strange as I can see it working on the fiddle. I've updated [the fiddle] (http://jsfiddle.net/YHLz2/25/) with more of my html and css to see if you can spot a mistake although I tested it with w3 schools and it showed up fine. I've used the last script that worked. My problem is that when I load the page all of the images from the cycle plugins in seperate divs all overlap each other in the first div but when I click on my logo, linked to index.html, the whole page works fine and the images go back to correct divs.

Comment: Hi Eicto, I've put the site (http://colm-mccarthy.com/) online so you can view it.

Comment: @Francis try to use latest cycle plugin, your one released 2008 , latest in 2012 http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle.all.js

Comment: @Francis added another option to try

Comment: _try to use latest cycle plugin, your one released 2008 , latest in 2012 malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle.all.js_ This was my problem! Thank you very much eicto. I would've never spotted that! It works perfect now :)