# jquery cycle, multiple on page

Tags: jquery, cycle

hello im trying to have multiple jquery cycle galleries on one page. ifeel like i have the code right but its not working... can anyone look at and help?  it doesnt seem to finding my .next and .prev classes?

jquery:

```
$('.cycle').each(function() {
    var slideshow = $(this);
    var next = slideshow.closest('.next');
    var prev = slideshow.closest('.prev');

    slideshow.cycle({
        speed: 0,
        timeout: 0, 
        next: next, 
        prev: prev,
    });
});
```

html:

```
<div id="woodwood" class="drag">
    <div class='cycle'>
        <img src='invites/baldi.png' />
        <img src='invites/koerfer.png' />
        <img src='invites/williams.png' />
    </div>
    <div class="title">
        Invites<br />
        2010 &mdash; 2012
    </div>
    <div class="controls">
        <a class='prev'><img src="left.gif"></a>
        <a class='next'><img src="right.gif"></a>
        <button>Close</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: <div >
        <ul class='cycle'><img src='invites/baldi.png' />
        <img src='invites/koerfer.png' />
        <img src='invites/williams.png' />
</ul>
    </div>

Comment: I think problem of your html structure , Please follow the steps mentioned above , Add ul li steps and set class <ul class='cycle'>"

Comment: we assumed in end that plugin version was too old
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13003143/jquery-cycle-plugin-multiple-divs-with-cycle-plugin-from-one-script/13003412#13003412

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `closest` selects the closest parent not the closest element, you can use `find` method.

```
var next = slideshow.parent().find('.next');
var prev = slideshow.parent().find('.prev');
```

Note that IDs must be unique, if you have several wrappers with ID of `woodwood` your markup is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with finding `.next` and `.prev`

Change theses lines,

```
var next = slideshow.closest('.next');
var prev = slideshow.closest('.prev');
```

To,

```
 var next = $('.next');
 var prev = $('.prev');
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/muthkum/egZ3y/1/